# How to filter array of custom type in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have an array of devices that look like this.

```js
export interface Device {
    id:                      Number;
    tracker_status?:         Trackerstatus;
}


export interface Trackerstatus {
    last_update?: Date;
    battery_low?: any;
}
```

applying a filter like

```js
function filterDevices(device: any) {
    if (device.id == 5){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

works perfectly fine.

however what i am trying to do is

```js
function filterDevices(device: any) {
  if (device.tracker_status.battery_low == "true"){
    return true;
  }else{
  return false;
  }
}
```

this just returns an empty list with no error messages. what am i doing wrong?

the goal is to show the filtered data in an angular table. i am using the filter like this

```js
devices: Device[] = data.filter(filterDevices);
```

Comment: Please show how you are using the `filterDevices` function, some example data, and the desired output?

Comment: updated it. more clear now

Answer (score 0):

You're checking against the string `"true"`. Did you check if the `device.tracker_status.battery_low` property is a boolean or a string?

Note that both `true == "true"` and `false == "true"` would return `false`.

```js
console.log(true == "true");
console.log(false == "true");
```

I'd suggest the following

```js
function filterDevices(device: any) {
  return !!(device?.tracker_status?.battery_low);
}
```

1. More about the double-negation operator `!!` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784946/6513921).
2. More about the optional-chaining operator `?.` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. forgot to check console logs

simply checking if tracker status is not null since not every device has it solved the problem.

Comment: Please do not answer your question as a comment. You can write your comment to your question.